# My android can send message but cannot receive message

Tags: hardware, mobile-data, internet, vivo

I am using Vivo S1 and I have some issues recently.

My phone works perfectly when using WiFi or tethering from another phone. But when I use mobile data from my SIM card, I cannot load anything and cannot receive any messages from messaging apps.

It is more strange that I COULD NOT RECEIVE messages from message apps (Line, Discord, etc) except WhatsApp, BUT ACTUALLY CAN send messages through those apps. So, anyone I send a message to can read my message.

I am assuming I have my hardware broken, but still have a doubt. Any idea what exactly causes the problem?

Comment: Since this only happens on mobile data, I think a hardware problem is unlikely. On the other hand, your carrier probably has a special plan/quota related to messaging apps. You might need to confirm with them though.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I'm going to contact my carrier to confirm my plan and the issue. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: maybe the apps are not allowed to use background data